# Javascript: for-loop returning array of booleans instead of array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback

In my code below, I created a   `fn` callback function to return `values < 2`, after the loop in the `map` function runs through the array passed as the parameter. But the console is logging an array of booleans instead of values

What am I doing wrong?

```
 var newarr = []

function fn(val){
  return val < 3;
}

function map(arr){
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    newarr.push(fn(arr[i]));
  }
  console.log(newarr);
}

map ([1,2,3,4,5,6], fn);
```

My Result

```
[ true, true, false, false, false, false ]
```

Comment: `val < 3` is a condition check and will return Boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because result of `fn` is boolean:

```
return val < 3; // true or false
```

If you need to *filter* elements, then the logic should be a little bit different, and the name should be `filter`, not `map`:

```
var newarr = [];

function fn(val) {
  return val < 3;
}

function filter(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (fn(arr[i])) {
      newarr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(newarr);
}
```

Also ES6 natively supports `Array#filter` function:

```
let newArray = arr.filter(item => item < 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with your callback for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

correction in your code:

```js
var newarr = []

function fn(val){
  return val < 3;
}

function map(arr){
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
if(fn(arr[i]))
      newarr.push(arr[i]);
  }
  console.log(newarr);
}

map ([1,2,3,4,5,6], fn);
```

and ES6 code for the same solution

```js
var newarr = [1,2,3,4,5,6].filter(function(item){
return item<3;
})
console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this -  [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var newArr = arr.filter((val) => val < 3); // [1,2]
```